# Bootstrap collapse can't hide

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Not able to collapse the bootstap

```
<a href="#demo" data-toggle="collapse">Collapsible</a>

<div id="demo" class="collapse">
@item.Ans
</div
```

Comment: what version of bootstrap?

Comment: Use `' ..'` instead `" "` in `'#QuizForHint'`:  `<a href="@('#QuizForHint'+i)" id="getAnsHint"  class="btn"  data-toggle="collapse">Quiz Hint</a>`

Comment: it's not working i've tried

Comment: see my answer please

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know, because you didn't share all the relevant code, but note that you're using the same id for multiple elements (`id="getAnsHint"`) this is not a vaild HTML, and if the collapse code relies on the id it probably won't work

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `QuizforHint`. I think didn't try it thou but to your html generetared like this `<a href=someid123 >` this cause it

```
@foreach (var item in Model){

<a href="'@("#QuizForHint"+i)'" id="getAnsHint"  class="btn"  data-toggle="collapse">Quiz Hint</a>
<div id='"@("QuizForHint"+i)"' class="collapse">
        <span style=" border: 1px solid;>@item.QuizForHint</span>
</div>
```

also could you share your html like how its generated from your each

Comment: " '@("#QuizForHint"+i)' "

Comment: @foreach (var item in Model){

    <a href="@("#QuizForHint"+i)" id="getAnsHint"  class="btn"  data-toggle="collapse">Quiz Hint</a>
    <div id="@("QuizForHint"+i)" class="collapse">
            <span style=" border: 1px solid;>@item.QuizForHint</span>
    </div>

Comment: @Kuan you must use `data-target` see in my answer

Comment: hey would you edit your code in your answer, also attach with your screen save or whatever

Answer (score 0):

1. use Use `' ..'` instead `" "` in `"@('#QuizForHint/getAnsHint'+i)"`
2. use `data-target`:https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible&stacked=h
3. set a unique `id` to each  `a`
4. close style with `"`:  `style=" border: 1px solid;"`

```html
    @foreach (var item in Model){
    <a href="@('#QuizForHint'+i)" id="@('getAnsHint'+i)"  class="btn"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="@('QuizForHint'+i)">Quiz Hint</a>
            <div id="@('QuizForHint'+i)" class="collapse">
                    <span style=" border: 1px solid;">@item.QuizForHint</span>
            </div>
    }
```

Comment: tell me for more help:)